# Image to byte[] to Image

Tags: java, eclipse, image

I'm trying to do some image processing using with Java.
As a start, before doing any filters or anything, I'm doing a convert process on my image to a byte array, then convert it back to an image and save it to see how that goes.

I'm not getting the output image as the input one, there is some lost information/data, which causing the output to look different in colors.

Please tell me what is the problem; what I am missing.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class Ola {

    BufferedImage img = null;

    public void loadImage() {
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("/home/a/Pictures/Tux-vegeta.png"));
           } catch (IOException e) {
               System.out.println("image(s) could not load correctly, try changing the path");
           }
    }

    public byte[] convertToArray() {
        int w = img.getWidth();
        int h = img.getHeight();

        int bands = img.getSampleModel().getNumBands();
        System.out.print(bands);

        if (bands != 4) {
            System.out.println("The image does not have 4 color bands");            
        }

        byte bytes[] = new byte[4 * w * h];
        int index = 0;

        for(int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
                int pixel = img.getRGB(x, y);

                int alpha = (pixel >> 24) & 0xFF;
                int red = (pixel >> 16) & 0xFF;
                int green = (pixel >> 8) & 0xFF;
                int blue = pixel & 0xFF;

                bytes[index++] = (byte) alpha;
                bytes[index++] = (byte) red;
                bytes[index++] = (byte) green;
                bytes[index++] = (byte) blue;
           }
        }
        return bytes;   
    }
    public void convertToImage(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            int w = 300;
            int h = 300;
            int index = 0;
            BufferedImage resultPNG = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < w; j ++) {
                    int pixel = (bytes[index] << 24) | (bytes[index + 1] << 16) | (bytes[index + 2] << 8) | (bytes[index + 3]);
                    resultPNG.setRGB(j, i, pixel);
                    index += 4;
                }
            }
            File outputImage = new File("/home/a![enter image description here][1]/Pictures/test.png");
            ImageIO.write(resultPNG, "png", outputImage);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("image write error");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ola ola = new Ola();
        ola.loadImage();
        ola.convertToImage(ola.convertToArray());

    }
}
```

Comment: You could use a ByteArrayInput/OutputStream and ImageIO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are missing is turning your signed byte back to unsigned:

change your line

```
int pixel = (bytes[index] << 24) | (bytes[index + 1] << 16) | (bytes[index + 2] << 8) | (bytes[index + 3]);
```

to the following:

```
int pixel = ((bytes[index] & 0xFF) << 24) | ((bytes[index + 1] & 0xFF) << 16) | ((bytes[index + 2] & 0xFF) << 8) | (bytes[index + 3]  & 0xFF);
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, I don't know how i missed that.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are wanting the alpha channel your destination should be using TYPE_INT_ARGB instead of TYPE_INT_RGB, using RGB will cause the buffered image to ignore the alpha byte.

Since PNGs do not load into the TYPE_INT_ARGB color model you can use a graphics object to draw the loaded bufferedimage into a bufferedimage object created with TYPE_INT_ARGB.

```
public void loadImage() {
    try {
         BufferedImage tempimg = ImageIO.read(new File("/home/a/Pictures/Tux-vegeta.png"));
         img = new BufferedImage(300, 300, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
         Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
         g2.drawImage(tempimg,null,0,0);
       } catch (IOException e) {
           System.out.println("image(s) could not load correctly, try changing the path");
       }
}
```

Comment: No, still getting the same output.

Comment: Looking in to it a bit more, PNGs do not appear to load into the TYPE_INT_ARGB or RGB color spaces.  You will need to look into the exact format PNGs are loading into.

Comment: The type that PNG is loading into varies depending on the actual file. Particularly, when it is a PNG that contains transparency, then the type may be TYPE_CUSTOM. Thus, it is in general a good idea to paint a BufferedImage that was freshly loaded from a PNG into a new image with type TYPE_INT_ARGB (this may also increase painting performance!). (This was not related to the original question, but I did NOT downvote your answer, BTW)